# how can I remove objects in a list if it's also in another list in java, iBatis?

Tags: java, ibatis

I have a problem with removing some objects from a list in java. I'm using ibatis and have two list; both lists are created by different sql queries. I'm sending both lists to the same result map which means same bean class. If second list have same rows with the first one I want to remove them from the first list.

```
            lst = dao.listWaitingCustomers(totalThreadCount , jobNumber);
            List lst2 = dao.listWaitingCustomers2();
            lst.removeAll(lst2);
```

But this does not work because I think even same rows return from db, they're not in same reference I mean they're different objects. How can remove those objects from one list if they have same column values?

Comment: give us the class structure of your data model. which means the `something.java` which is being populated by the query

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the equals and the hashcode method of the object that you are storing in the lists.